# Designing Exception, usage and definition

Tags: c#, exception, design-patterns

I just want to know what do you think about where to define, throw and catch Exception and see if there is a consensus about does consideration.

Let me state an example to base on.
Let say I have solution and in that solution I have 2 projects: `DomainProject` and `ControllerProject`.

1. In the DomainProject I have a repository for doing some query for instance in the `RepositoryClass` I have the method:

   ```
   GetObjectById(int id) { ... }
   ```

   And I have some Exception define in this project like `ObjectNotFoundException`.
2. In the `ControllerProject` I want to query my repository so I do something that would look like:

   ```
   MyObject obj = repo.GetObjectById(11);
   ```

Now the question is who should take care of checking if the id does really exist. If you choose that the ControllerProject should check for the existence of the id you can end up with some code like this:

```
MyObject obj = repo.GetObjectById(11);
if (obj == null) {throw new ObjectNotFoundException();}
```

But the down side of that is that it tend to be duplicate all over the place where `GetObjectById` is used. Of course there is some situation where you won't care if you get a null value so it somehow legitimate to not throw the exception in the DomainProject directly. But I first don't like to duplicate the if test and second, more related to my question, I don't like to use an exception define outside the current project.

I have the feeling that an Exceptions should only be throw in the project where it is define and other projects should only be catching them.

So back to my example, how would I solve this situation. Well a simple idea is to define 2 method in my domain project. One that throw an exception and one that does not. The only thing that I am not sure of is which naming convention I have to used: `GetObjectByIdThrowsIfNotFound()` and `GetObjectById()`. Or may be I can just add an optional parameter `GetObjectById(int id, bool isExceptionThrow = true)`.

What do you think about the Exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is great that you are being thoughtful about how to let your design properly communicate intent.  I agree with your misgivings: the only layer throwing the exception should be the layer that defined the exception.

That said, you only need an exception-throwing variant if a null return value is ambiguous, if it is valid to associate a key with a `null`.  If not (and this should be noted in your XML comments!), then a null return always means the same thing (value not found) and you can save yourself the code and processing overhead of an exception in you Domain layer.  If 'value not found' is a truly exceptional event in your Controller layer, define and throw the exception there.

If a 'stored `null`' *is* valid, I use the semantic pattern established by `IDictionary<T>`: `bool TryGetObjectById(int id, out object value)`, and I only include an exception-throwing `GetObjectById(int key)` variant if a key-not-found is truly exceptional, and I want to save the keystrokes involved in calling the `Try...` variant down the road.

Comment: Try.. seems a good established pattern thanks for that answer. But instead of a the out object value I would prefer to have a lambda that it is invoke only when the object is not found.

Comment: @mathk: I consider myself a *big* fan of lambdas--I use Autofac!-- but while interesting that seems to smack of using lambdas for the sake of lambdas.  Another example may sway me, but `if (TryGetX(id, out val)) {yes...;} else {no...;}` is far more expressive than `var val = GetXElse(id, () => {no...;}); if (???) {yes...;}`, even leaving aside what goes in the latter `if(???)`.  But if you like it that's okay, the underlying point still holds: you only need variants at all if a `null` return is ambiguous.  And if you don't need them, including them will obfuscate your intent.

Answer (score 0):

There are two patterns I see often:

1) The repository itself should throw the exception, and your calling method should wrap in a try / catch block if you want to handle the failure to get the item. I think this pattern would be the prime candidate for your application since it's the responsibility of the caller to deal with exceptions. I would assume that your repository doesnt catch `SqlException` or whatever persistence layer exceptions get thrown right? If so, then you should let the repository throw the exception and let it bubble up the stack.

If not....

2) You expose the object wrapped in a container to tell you of failure or success:

```
public class RepositoryItemContainer<DataType>
{
    public DataType Object { get; set; }
    public bool WasFound { get; set; }
}
```

Then, instead of just returning the value, you return this wrapper and the code can then decide what it wants to do:

```
var repoItem = _repo.GetObjectById(11);

if(repoItem.WasFound)
   var item = repoItem.Object;

else
   throw new ApplicationSpecificException("Wasnt found yo!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are just a couple of considerations:

1. The `Exceptions` are for *exceptional*  situations. So if you think that absence of the object in DB is an *exceptional* situation, I would say go in the way you implement it now.
2. If it's not exceptional case, implement  a method in a way that it does not raise and `Exception`, but returns `null`, in case the `id` we query for is missed, naturally. Seems natural and keeps expected behaviour for a developer that will consume the repo class you implemented.
3. You can add kind of `ContainsId(long id)` method, that first checks for presence of requiered `id` in DB. Could be a good choice too, but I personally would prefer second point.

Hope this helps.